# Recursive Steiner Chains

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, fractal, recursion

Steiner Chains are a set of N circles where each circle is tangent to 2 other non-intersecting circles as well as the the previous and next circles of the chain, as seen in the below images:

[image: Order 3] [image: Order 5] [image: Order 7]

In this challenge, you will write a program/function that draws Steiner chains recursively, that is, circles of a given chain will be the base circles of another iteration of chains:

[image]

## Challenge

Write a program/function that accepts image dimensions and a list of integers denoting the level of circles in each successive iteration of chains, and output an image with the recursive Steiner chains drawn to it.

## Input

Your program/function will accept 2 arguments:

- `s` - width and height of image
- `ls` - list of positive integers denoting the number of circles present in each successive iteration of chains, ordered from the top-most chain to the bottom-most chain

## Output

Your program/function will output an image of dimension `s` x `s` displaying the recusive Steiner chain.

- The top level base circle will be as large as the image with a diameter of `s`, centered inside the image
- To make things easy, the 2 base circles of a Steiner chain will be concentric, that is, the centerpoints of the 2 baseline circles will be the same
- Given an outer radius, `R`, and the number of circles in a chain, `N`, the formula for the inner radius `R'` is `R' = (R-R*sin(pi/N))/(sin(pi/N)+1)`
- Circles of the chain as well as the inner base circle will be the outer base circles of the next iteration of chains
- While recursing through the chain circles, the order of the next chain should correspond to the next value in `ls`
- While recursing through the inner circle of a chain, the order should be the same as its parents order (example [5,2]):
- [image: Order 5.2]
- All chains should end recursion at a depth of the length of `ls`
- The rotation of the chains doesn't matter:
- [image: Rotation 1] [image: Rotation 2]
- However, the rotations of recursive chains relative to their parents centerpoint should be the same:
- [image: Order 5.2] [image: Invalid Order 5.2]
- All circles should be drawn with an outline or solid fill
- Color choice is left to the implementation, save for loopholes (for example, filling everything with the same color)

## Example Runs

In the following examples, color is determined by `(depth of the recursion)^4`.

You can find source [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80152/recursive-steiner-chains/80154#80154).

```
chain(600,[5,4,3])
```

[image: 5.4.3]

```
chain(600,[11,1,1,1,1,1,1])
```

[image: 11.1.1.1.1.1.1]

```
chain(600,[5,6,7,8,9])
```

[image: 5.6.7.8.9]

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38450/8478)

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript ES6, 379 bytes

This solution was used to generate the example runs in the question.

```
f=(s,ls)=>{with(V=document.createElement`canvas`)with(getContext`2d`)with(Math)return(width=height=s,translate(s/=2,s),(S=(o,d=0,n=ls[d],i=(o-o*sin(PI/n))/(sin(PI/n)+1),r=0)=>{fillStyle=`rgba(0,0,0,${pow(d/ls.length,4)})`;beginPath(),arc(0,0,o,-PI,PI),fill();if(d++<ls.length){S(i,d,n);for(;r<n;++r){save();translate(0,(o+i)/2);S((o-i)/2,d);restore();rotate((2*PI)/n);}}})(s),V)}
```

Ungolfed:

```
f=(s,ls)=>{                                        // define function that accepts image dimensions and a list of orders
 with(V=document.createElement`canvas`)            // create canvas to draw on, bring its functions into current scope chain
 with(getContext`2d`)                              // bring graphics functions into current scope chain
 with(Math)return(                                 // bring Math functions into current scope chain
  width=height=s,                                  // set width and height of image
  translate(s/=2,s),                               // center the transform on image
   (S=(o,d=0,                                      // define recursive function that accepts outer radius, depth, and optionally order
       n=ls[d],                                    // default chain order to corresponding order in input list
       i=(o-o*sin(PI/n))/(sin(PI/n)+1),            // calculate inner base circle radius
       r=0)=>{                                     // initialize for loop var
    fillStyle=`rgba(0,0,0,${pow(d/ls.length,4)})`; // fill based on depth
    beginPath(),arc(0,0,o,-PI,PI),fill();          // draw circle
    if(d++<ls.length){                             // if within recursion limit
     S(i,d,n);                                     //   recurse on inner circle
     for(;r<n;++r){                                //   loop through all circles of the chain
      save();                                      //   save transform
      translate(0,(o+i)/2);                        //   translate origin to middle of the 2 base circles
      S((o-i)/2,d);                                //   recurse on chain circle
      restore();                                   //   restore transform
      rotate((2*PI)/n);                            //   rotate transform to next circle in chain
   }}})(s),                                        // begin the recursion
 V)}                                               // return the canvas
```

Note: `f` returns a canvas.

Example run (assumes there's a `<body>` to append to):

```
document.body.appendChild(f(600,[13,7,11,5,3]))
```

Should dump the following image to the page:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

@Dendrobium

I was trying to port @Dendrobium's Javascript answer in Python.

\$\color{red}{\text{But the resolution of my fractal image is terrible.}}\$

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw_fractal(s, ls):
    # Create a new image with a white background
    image = Image.new('RGBA', (s, s), color = (0, 0, 0, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    
    # Begin the recursion
    draw_fractal_recursive(draw, s/2, s/2, s/2, 0, ls, s)
    
    # Display the image
    plt.imshow(np.array(image))
    plt.show()

def draw_fractal_recursive(draw, x, y, o, depth, ls, s):
    if depth >= len(ls):
        return

    # Chain order to corresponding order in input list
    n = ls[depth]
    
    # Calculate inner base circle radius
    i = (o-o*np.sin(np.pi/n))/(np.sin(np.pi/n)+1)
    
    # Fill based on depth
    rgba_color = (0, 0, 0, int(255 * np.power(depth/len(ls), 4)))

    # Draw circle
    draw.ellipse((x-o, y-o, x+o, y+o), fill=rgba_color)

    # Recurse on inner circle
    draw_fractal_recursive(draw, x, y, i, depth+1, ls, s)

    # Loop through all circles of the chain
    for r in range(n):
        # Translate origin to middle of the 2 base circles
        new_x = x + (o+i)/2 * np.cos(2 * np.pi * r / n)
        new_y = y + (o+i)/2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * r / n)
        
        # Recurse on chain circle
        draw_fractal_recursive(draw, new_x, new_y, (o-i)/2, depth+1, ls, s)

# Call the function
draw_fractal(600,[13,7,11,5,3])
```

[image]